# Instagram Posts Filtering Not Working - Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to filter Instagram posts by type, but the API seems to be ignoring my "filtering" parameter.

This is my request URL:

- https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/media?fields=timestamp,permalink,media_type,thumbnail_url,media_url,caption,comments_count,like_count,insights.metric(impressions,reach,saved)&filtering=[{field:"media.media_type",operator:"IN",value:["VIDEO"]}]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this `filtering` parameter that you are basing this on? I am assuming `[PAGE_ID]` is actually an IG User ID, so the endpoint you are using here would be this one then, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media ?

Comment: You are right, this is the user id. Ultimately, what I am trying to do is filter the posts by media type. I did not find any documentation on that. Do you have any guidance on that?

Comment: If you did not get this from the documentation, then where _did_ you get it from? // With the Facebook Graph API, only some endpoints allow any kind of filtering to begin with - they mostly argue performance reasons, sending more data than necessary and have app developers do the filtering on their end, seems to be the approach they decided works better for the overall Graph API eco system. I would expect that to be no different with the new IG APIs - so unless filtering is explicitly documented somewhere, and that it is applicable for the endpoint you are using - it probably doesn’t exist.

Comment: I will have to filter the data at my end then.