# Facebook Instagram Graph API Filter Media Type in API request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to find a way to filter the media_type results of the API request directly inside the request.

So basically I only want the results from the API to return results where the `media_type` is not `VIDEO`.

I have checked other answers from Stack but it seems no one has figured it out (might it not be possible?)

[Instagram Posts Filtering Not Working - Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209989/instagram-posts-filtering-not-working-facebook-graph-api)

I'm testing this within Insomnia so I'll post the URL it generates for the request:

`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,insights,children%7Bmedia_url,media_type%7D,thumbnail_url,username,caption,media_type%7BIMAGE%7D,media_url,permalink&access_token=<TOKEN>&limit=18`

Human readable:

`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,insights,children{media_url,media_type},thumbnail_url,username,caption,media_type{IMAGE},media_url,permalink&access_token=<TOKEN>&limit=18`

In the Facebook fields docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media/#fields they mention that the media_type can be one of 3 options, so I want to think there's a way to filter your results directly from the request instead of handling it in code

Comment: Did you have any update about this? I found that you can filter the 'media_product_type'  as media_product_type{FEED}, but not the 'media_type'.

Comment: @Sprizgola I'm using only the Instagram Basic Display API which doesn't have that field from what I've seen from the docs. So it seems you're using the full-blown instagram graph 

No i haven't found a solution, currently I'm taking care of this via code by manipulating the returned results from the API

Comment: Unfortunatly looks like that the documentation is incomplete or insufficient for what I am looking for; thank you anyway @Uriahs Victor.